# Facebook sharing comment issue

Tags: android, facebook

Here i develop one android application from which i want to share some text,picture on facebook, here i use facebook-sdk of github to share text or picrure.

Here is the code which i implement.

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", "對此發意見");
parameters.putString("picture", "http://app3.sdt.net.tw/MIT/FBshare.jpg");
parameters.putString("name", "台灣製MIT微笑標章官方粉絲團支持台灣製造，就要用台灣製MIT微笑產品。");
parameters.putString("description", "台灣製MIT微笑標章官方粉絲團支持台灣製造，就要用台灣製MIT微笑產品。");
facebook.dialog(Function3_1_Activity.this, "stream.publish", parameters,new PostDialogListener());
```

and i implement PostDialogListener() in my code.

here it works fine but the problem is that.

[image]

Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

I am stuck with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("name","SampleImage");
        parameters.putString("caption", "Demo");
        parameters.putString("description", "Testing App");
        parameters.putString("link","http://www.google.com");
```